# Including Sharepoint /pages/ in Import/Export

Tags: sharepoint, import, export

My team and I are using multiple virtual machines on our local computers to develop a Sharepoint Site and, as this is really not supported, we are running into problems:

I am attempting to use the in-house import/export features with the following commands:

-- Export --
stsadm.exe -o export -url http://localhost/ -nologfile -haltonwarning -haltonfatalerror -overwrite -filename ClintonAWAS.sharepoint

-- Import --
stsadm.exe -o import -url http://localhost/ -nologfile -haltonwarning -haltonfatalerror -filename CoreyAWAS.sharepoint

Everything seems to have been brought over properly including the DB connections, with the exception of one important detail: the .aspx files in the /pages/ virtual directory.  So far, we have had to export/import them manually, file-by-file in designer.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there another way to do this?  Can anyone suggest anything?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally avoid doing this sort of site copying between developers - solution package projects with source control works much better - but if you are stuck with this sort of environment you may find the content deployment wizard quite useful.

Another thing to check is if the pages are published - copying a site with pages that have no published version can get you interesting results.